# understanding the push function in solidity

Tags: solidity

I am a beginner in solidity and I'm trying to conceptualize the push function.

for example

```
uint id = zombies.push(Zombie(_name, _dna)) - 1;
```

I would have thought making id equal to a push function would make it equal to the contents of the array(as a beginner) but it returns the length. Is it just how it is? what if we did

```
id = zombies.push(Zombie(_name, _dna));
```

does this mean anything^? apologies if my question is incoherent

Answer (score 0):

as you say using push in some array return the length, so if you want the content you should do something like this `Zombie memory zombie = zombies[id - 1]`